# How to Modify AJAX Based site Content OnDocumentComplete Event

Tags: html, ajax, bho

I have an IE tool bar application under the DocumentComplete Event of the Page , i was disabling the HTML links using Concept of BHO(Browser Helper Object) that is working well for some of the sites but when i browse some AJAX/JQUERY based sites ,where the data will be popuplated dynamically and more over source code is also not vsible for dynamic data,this link disabling feature is not working.....

How To Disable or Modify the Content Of Dynamic Data When We load into browser??

```
HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
IHTMLElementCollection hh = ((IHTMLElementCollection)document.getElementsByTagName("a"));

foreach (IHTMLElement ht in hh)
{

 ((HTMLAnchorElement)ht).removeAttribute("href", 1);
 ((HTMLAnchorElement)ht).style.color = "#b9b0b0";

}
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your IE version. Till IE 8 there is no [DOM Mutation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) generated but there is an alternative approach as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108993/is-there-an-event-that-fires-when-dom-is-modified-in-mshtml-ie8). Although IE 9 supports some basic dom mutation events as mentioned in [this IE blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/26/dom-level-3-events-support-in-ie9.aspx). Also, see this [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the supported interface in IE9.

A very ***crude*** approach is to use a timer event for monitoring any changes in the DOM content. But you have to take care of threading issues and have to keep per window text information (by window I mean tabs and also IFrame content).

Another approach is to use [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for monitoring any Ajax request and then accordingly notifying the appropriate tab/window. This is harder then the previous ***crude*** approach.

Comment: Thank You for the comment. I got answer for the above mentioned problem.the following are the resolution steps what i have followed for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for the above mentioned problem. The following are the resolution steps what I have followed for the issue.

I just read the whole page content into "MSHTML" object as mentioned in the question

```
 HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
```

and again I just loaded it into a Web Browser control.

From there I can read the data easily and I just removed "href" property.